# How to jump to label inside a macro/function that returns a value

Tags: c, macros, goto

I have the following function:

```
enum MqErrorE ReadI(struct MqS* ctx, int *i);
```

The function stores a result in `i` and returns `OK` or `ERROR` flag.

If the function returns `ERROR`, I want to jump to a label called `error`.

```
int i; 
if (ReadI(ctx,&i) == ERROR)
    goto error; 
// ...
error:
    // do some error processing
```

To make the code more "user-friendly" I would like to do something like:

```
int i; 
i = ReadI_something(ctx); // on error jump to "label" 
// ... 
error: 
    //...
```

In other words, I need `ReadI_something` to return a value but also to be able to jump to the label.

As a restriction I want to avoid using `longjmp`/`setjmp`.

How can I write a macro or function to do so?

Comment: What is the difference between "goto a central error-processing label: error" and "call an error processing function"? What is the reason for using a method which I consider extinct with C64 basic? What forces you to do it this way?

Comment: @Yunnosch
1. if u use a error-processing-function `epf` you end up in the same problem as above just replace "goto label" with `return epf(…)`…
2. BUT the `epf` has NO access to the variables in the context
> this mean you have ti write a "specific" `epf`-call for every "usage"

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use the [GNU statement expression extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) (supported in gcc, clang and icc), it is pretty straightforward:

```
#define ReadI_something(ctx) \
    ({ \
        int i; \
        if (ReadI(ctx, &i) == ERROR) \
            goto error; \
        i; \
    })
```

Then you can do:

```
int i = ReadI_something(ctx);
```

Comment: When you start *brace wrapping* macros -- it's time to rewrite the macro as a function... This is non-portable and your compiler should warn that you are using an extension.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: it is not possible to write it as a function if you want to jump to a label (6.8.6.1.1); and OP said it wasn't possible to use `setjump`/`longjmp`. As for being portable, in practice it is so since it is supported by the 3 major compilers.

Comment: Not saying you can't use it, obviously it was created as an extension to serve just the purpose you are putting it to. What I'm saying is given the option of a function or brace-enclosed macro -- go with the function. You eliminate all portability issues and pitfalls associated with macro use. It is convenient as hell to use, but you end up re-writing lots of code if you need to compile on windoze.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I guess you are referring to MSVC -- you could always use the other compilers in that case. And, *technically*, MSVC is not a C compiler anyway so we could just ignore it in questions tagged as C. :)

Comment: I was talking about the VS compiler `cl.exe`.